# Distribution of the midrange in the general case

Tags: probability, order-statistics

Given an iid sample  $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ drawn from a  sufficiently nice (finite expectation, maybe L2 integrable, etc.) distribution, I want I want to know the population CDF of the mid-range or center point

$$ C(x) = \mathbb P \left[\frac {\max X_i+\min X_i}2 \leq 2x\right] = \mathbb P(\max X_i+\min X_i \leq 2x)$$

or at least some interesting facts and inequalities about it. This isn't a homework problem so nailing an answer  for an exact question isn't important. Maybe this is easy with extra assumptions? 
I will obviously report the results of my continued research here for everyone to share.

These are my goals. Let me share my best work so far.

---

The density $C'(x)$ has to be the convolution of the densities for $\min X_i, \max X_i$ whose CDF is respectively
$$ m(x) = [\mathbb P(X<x)]^n $$

and for symmetric reasons

$$ M(x) = [1-\mathbb P(X<x)]^n $$

What I have in my Batman utility belt is the Laplace transform. (**Edit: as per comments below, I passed over the fact that $\min X_i, \max X_i$ are not independent r.v.s so the convolution method doesn't apply. Please refer to the nice accepted answer**) It's nice because $\mathcal L(M'(x)) = s\mathcal L(M)(s)$ so

$$ m'*M' = \mathcal L^{-1} \left\{[s\mathcal L(m)(s)] [s\mathcal L(M)(s)]\right\} = \mathcal L^{-1} \{ s^2 \left([\mathcal Lm](s) \cdot [\mathcal LM](s)\right) $$

and um, frantically going over the [list of common facts about the Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems),  we see that

$$ \mathcal L^{-1} \{s^2 [\mathcal Lf(s)] - f'(0) \} = f''(x)$$

which would be awesome if I was trying to inverse Laplace $s^2(\mathcal Lm + \mathcal LM) = s^2 \mathcal (L+M)$ rather than $s^2[\mathcal L m]\cdot [\mathcal LM]$. Which is close enough to be frustrating.

I'm at a loss by now. Am I even going in the right direction?

Comment: You might want to look at the Wikipedia page on order statistics, and search questions here that contain the term

Comment: $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$ are _not_ independent random variables and so the density of their sum is not the convolution of their marginal densities.

Comment: In the absolutely continuous case, there is a formula for the joint density of any pair of order statistics [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution)

Comment: I jumped too fast to the convolution approach. I have to edit the post later to see what's salvageable.

Comment: Did you try working with the joint pdf of $(\min X_i,\max X_i)$ ?

Comment: I'm unsure of how to proceed with that. The CDF of the joint gives me a number in [0,1] for every pair of values (a,b). I want a function from c=a+b to [0,1] but there any many (many, many, many) such (a,b) pairs,

Comment: There seem to be too many "2"s in your displayed equation. // Also, several math stat books on my shelf show how to find the distribution of the range (max - min), and getting the dist'n of the midrange ought to be similar. // I know of no way to invert a Laplace transform (moment-generating function), but there is an inversion formula for characteristic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As currently stated, the equation at the top of the question appears to have an extra (or missing) $2$ somewhere, so I will tackle the probability
$$
P\left(\min_i X_i + \max_i X_i \leq a\right)
$$
for an arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$ that you can scale as needed for your context.

> **Proposition 1.**
>   Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be an i.i.d. sample from an absolutely continuous distribution with probability density $f$ and cumulative distribution function $F$.
>   Let $X_{(1)} = \min_i X_i$ and $X_{(n)} = \max_i X_i$.
>   Then the joint density of $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$, call it $g$, is given by
>   $$
> g(x, y)
> = n (n - 1) \left(F(y) - F(x)\right)^{n - 2} f(x) f(y)
> $$
>   for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $x \leq y$ ($g(x, y) = 0$ otherwise).

*Proof.*
We first compute
$$
P(X_{(1)} \geq x, X_{(n)} \leq y)
$$
for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. This probability is clearly zero if $x > y$, so assume $x \leq y$.
Notice that
$$
\{X_{(1)} \geq x\}
= \{X_1 \geq x, \ldots, X_n \geq x\}
$$
and
$$
\{X_{(n)} \leq y\}
= \{X_1 \leq y, \ldots, X_n \leq y\},
$$
whence
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_{(1)} \geq x, X_{(n)} \leq y)
&= P(x \leq X_1 \leq y, \ldots, x \leq X_n \leq y) \\
&= P(x \leq X_1 \leq y) \cdots P(x \leq X_n \leq y) \\
&= \left(F(y) - F(x)\right)^n.
\end{aligned}
$$
Here we used the independence and identically-distributed-ness of $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ *and* the fact that their distributions are absolutely continuous.
To summarize,
$$
P(X_{(1)} \geq x, X_{(n)} \leq y)
= \begin{cases}
\left(F(y) - F(x)\right)^n & \text{if $x \leq y$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

The joint density of $(X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is now obtained [by differentiating](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111323/97872):
$$
g(x, y)
= -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} P(X_{(1)} \geq x, X_{(n)} \leq y)
$$
for a.e. $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
When $x > y$, both sides are zero, and when $x \leq y$, then a.e. we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(x, y)
&= -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} P(X_{(1)} \geq x, X_{(n)} \leq y) \\
&= -\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} \left(F(y) - F(x)\right)^n \\
&= n (n - 1) \left(F(y) - F(x)\right)^{n - 2} f(x) f(y),
\end{aligned}
$$
as claimed.

> **Proposition 2.**
>   With the same assumptions and notation as in Proposition 1, we have
>   $$
> P(X_{(1)} + X_{(n)} \leq a)
> = n (n - 1) \int_{-\infty}^{a / 2} f(x) \left(\int_x^{a - x} \left(F(y) - F(x)\right)^{n - 2} f(y) \, dy\right) \, dx.
> $$

*Proof.*
We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_{(1)} + X_{(n)} \leq a)
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{a - x} g(x, y) \, dy \, dx
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $g(x, y) = 0$ if $x > y$, this integral reduces to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{a/2} \int_x^{a - x} g(x, y) \, dy \, dx
$$
(draw the picture of the intersection of the regions $x \leq y$ and $x + y \leq a$ to see why).
Now just plug in the density formula from Proposition 1.